# Enable "real" right click on Windows 7 on a MacBook Pro

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, macbook-pro

Is there any way to enable a true right click (using the right side of the touchpad -- not using the two finger+click method) under Windows 7 on a MacBook Pro (new unibody model)?

This option is available under OSX, so I imagine its just a trackpad/boot camp driver feature that isn't available.  Are any third party drivers available enabling this?  I don't see an option in the Windows driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you install the BootCamp Services package in Windows, it will be an option from the BootCamp Control Panel.

Comment: Ahh, yes, its under TrackPad -> Secondary click.  thanks.

Answer (score 15):

1. Go to "Control Panel".
2. Click on the phrase "System and Security".
3. Then "Boot Camp".
4. Click on the "Trackpad" tab.
5. In the "One Finger" area, enable the checkbox next to "Secondary Click".
6. Click OK.